# JLabel is not showing, what am I missing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a Label for my GUI like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class Runner
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {


final int FRAME_WIDTH = 516;
final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;



final JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
myFrame.setTitle("Traveling Saleman Problem - GA solution");
myFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
final JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setLayout(null);


final JLabel genLabel = new JLabel("Number of Generations");
genLabel.setLocation(85,515);
myPanel.add(genLabel);


myFrame.add(myPanel);
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

I am adding it to the panel, adding the panel to the frame. I know that I am doing that right because I have buttons and TextFields showing when I run. Is there anything that I am missing from this code?

Comment: You need to `repaint/validate` your panel after adding components.

Comment: Can you post more code that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: I would highly recommend **against** using a null Layout. Instead choose the appropriate [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) based upon your layout requirements. Where to you wish to position your elements relative to each other?

Comment: I used the null layout because I'm hard coding the positions, creating a grid of buttons using an inner for loop. I'm sure that there was a better way to do it, but I have a limited knowledge of swing. I know there is the grid layout, but I am having text fields underneath the grid. Is there a way to add multiple layouts like in the android environment?

Comment: *"I know there is the grid layout, but I am having text fields underneath the grid. Is there a way to add multiple layouts like in the android environment?"*  Yes, and that is exactly what you would do here!  In fact, if you follow the link to **combinations of them** in my first comment, there is a complete code example.  That fact that you're not aware of that indicates you did *not* follow the link, so -1.

Comment: I'm sorry andrew. I saw the MCVE and assumed that was all your post was about. That is my bad, and thank you for the example it is a big help!!

Answer (score 2):

You biggest problem is using `null` layout. It is bound to spell trouble since graphics environments are different from each other. Factors like screen size (and resolution) and L&F must be taken into account, which is impossible with `null` layout.

Instead, you need to use a `LayoutManager` that suits your needs. It really depends on the overall GUI. Here I use the `JPanel`'s default `FlowLayout`:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Traveling Saleman Problem - GA solution");
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel genLabel = new JLabel("Number of Generations");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

        myPanel.add(textField);
        myPanel.add(genLabel);

        myFrame.add(myPanel);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- `setVisible(true)` is the default for a `JLabel`, so you don't need it.
- Don't `setSize` a `JFrame`, use `pack` instead.
- Calling `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` on the frame between the calls for `pack` and `setVisible` will center the frame on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a GridLayout,it's easy to use and well adapted for your example.

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
JLabel text=new JLabel("Try");
myPanel.add(text);
```

Comment: How would `GridLayout` suit the OP's needs? They didn't mention they need a gird.

Comment: Using a grid is convenient in the OP's case,if he only wants to add JLabel in his frame.

Comment: OP said "*I have buttons and TextFields showing when I run.*", which clearly negates "*only wants to add JLabel*". In any case, `GridLayout` is good when you actually want a *grid* of equal size components.

Comment: I do want a grid of equal sized components, but I also want text fields and labels underneath the grid. Can you walk me through adding another panel underneath the grid layout panel?

Comment: I wrote an example for you : `this.add(mypanel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);this.add(mypanel2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);`With "this" your window.

Comment: @KDowling Only way that you'll get what you want is to post a picture (draw something) of how you want your components to be arranged.

Answer (score -3):

```
getContentPane().add(genLabel);
```

Comment: 1) `setVisible` is `true` for a `JLabel` by default. 2) Don't set bounds, let the layout manager decide that.

Comment: i have changed my response

Comment: I am setting the bounds because I have a very specific place to place the label

Comment: @KDowling You can't place a component at a specific place because all graphics environments are different. You don't know the size of the screen and how the L&F (OS dependent) will handle the exact location.

Comment: Ok... I thought since the frame is a specific size that wouldn't matter. So how would I set the label to the right of a TextField?